# Teradata table creation and select statements fail when using LPAD and RPAD

Tags: sql, padding, teradata

Background: The application I'm working on is not using any character delimiters. Fields are fixed length. Alphanumeric fields have to be left justified and space filled to the right, and numeric fields are right justified and zero-filled to the left.

I've been trying to accomplish this by using the RPAD and LPAD functions. The problem I'm running into is the error Teradata is displaying, "Response Row size or Constant Row size overflow". Each record if 4000 Bytes, and (from what I've read) the maximum size for each record in Teradata is 64KB, so I'm well under the maximum Teradata-allowed length.

Here is a small sample of the code that is generating an error;

```
SELECT
    RPAD(t1.MemberNbr, 20, ' ') AS MemberNbr
    ,RPAD(t1.LastName, 35, ' ') AS LastName
    ,RPAD(t1.FirstName, 25, ' ') AS FirstName
,CAST(t1.B_Day AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') (char(8)) AS BirthDay
FROM someTable AS t1
```

Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you check the resulting data type (`SELECT TYPE(RPAD(t1.MemberNbr, 20, ' '))`) you will notice it's either a `VARCHAR(32000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE` or `VARCHAR(64000) CHARACTER SET LATIN`, you need to decrease it using a cast:

```
CAST(RPAD(t1.MemberNbr, 20, ' ') AS CHAR(20))
```

I know it's stupid, but `RPAD` & `LPAD` are no built-in functions but FastPath UDFs, thus the parser/optimizer doesn't seem to know about the actual result size (Otherwise it's ok for other UDFs, e.g. `LTRIM`/`RTRIM`)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that the fields were changed to VARCHAR(32000). Your solution worked perfectly, so thanks for the help.